# React "undefined" when posting with axios

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

Hello im trying to push some data to my API with axios and react but i keep getting undefined. i cant find my error what am i doing wrong would appreciate some help.

im using 2 components one to handle the inputs which seem to work i can see the fields filled with data

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export const useForm = (initialValues) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

    return [
        values,
        e => {
            setValues({
                ...values,
                [e.target.name]: e.target.values
            });

        }
    ]
}
```

and the component where do my API CALL

```
import "../Admin/admin.css";
import Axios from "axios";

import { useForm } from "./useForm";
// Displays booking with a person added.
const AddBookableTime = () => {
    const [values, handleChange] = useForm({ startTime: '', endTime: '' })
    const API_ENDPOINT = "https://localhost:44387/api/BookableHours";

    const PostBookingTimes = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let times = createBookingTimes(e);
        try {
            await Axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}`, times);

        } catch (err) {

        }
    };
    //Creating object to send to api
    const createBookingTimes = (e) => {
        let bookableHours = {
            startTime: e.target.values.startTime,
            endTime: e.target.values.endTime,
        };
        return bookableHours;
    };


    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={(e) => PostBookingTimes(e)}>

                <input type="text" name="startTime" value={values.startTime} onChange={handleChange} ></input>

                <input type="text" name="endTime" value={values.endTime} onChange={handleChange} ></input>
                <button type="submit" value="Post" className="booking-button">
                    Lägg till ny bokningsbar tid
            </button>
            </form>


        </>
    );

}

export default AddBookableTime;
```

Comment: `\`${API_ENDPOINT}\`` can be replaced with `API_ENDPOINT`!

Comment: your `createBookingTimes` method is not necessary. on submit you want to pass the values stored at your state. your post should be `await Axios.post(API_ENDPOINT, values);`

Comment: Hello i removed createBookingTimes and in the post i did 

           i still get undefined
            console.log(values)
            await Axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}`, values);

Comment: well, you didn't specify where you're getting undefined. btw, I believe `e.target.values` at your useForm should be singular `[e.target.name]: e.target.value`

Comment: i get this error in the console aswell while chaning the values of inputs

Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info

Comment: i get undefined when posting to the ApI

Comment: i tried the  [e.target.name]: e.target.value   without any effect

Comment: you didnt save your file then because I paste your code and that was the cause of the input error.

Comment: should be e.target.value not e.target.values.. try const {name, value} = e.target;  setValues({
                ...values,
                [name]: value
            });

Comment: don't use  e.target.value inside async function, instead, store the value inside variable and then [name]: value.

Comment: ok thanks! how can i pass my UseEffect from another component?